# Do American tourists get the Senior Discount in Vienna?

Tags: tickets, budget, vienna

I see a lot of museums in Vienna that offer reduced senior prices with "valid pensioner's ID." I assume that is an official government document. Would they accept an American passport or is the discount only for their country's elderly citizens?

Comment: Even within Vienna, each museum has its own rules for reduced tickets. I am voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: I have edited the header to match the body, making it less broad.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo if the answer is that there is no standardization, that's an answer. If there is a "best practice" used by most museums, that's also an answer. If there is a specific statute authoritatively defining eligibility for a "Vienna Senior Discount Program for Museums and Other Educational Venues", that's an even better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most Viennese museums request just a valid ID/Passport/Driving License which shows the age. Same is valid in rest of Austria. Other countries might have different rules.

For example, "The Kunsthistorische Museum" in Vienna mentions

- "Pensionisten ab 65 oder mit gültigem Pensionistenausweis"
- "Pensioners over 65 or with valid pensioner card"

The EU law does not allow more expensive ticket prices for non-Austrian Europeans. Same is valid for other EU countries. No special tariffs for locals (https://www.konsument.at/markt-dienstleistung/eu-einheimischentarife). There are few exceptions such general transport tickets. I haven't seen that museums request European passports on entry and it would be a hassle to verify if a pensioner id is connected to one of the 28 EU member countries. So I guess it doesn't matter from where you are.

Comment: From my personal experience in Austria, but also other European countries, this is correct and also applies to other discounts. For example any student ID would be OK, and it would be strange to reject a student ID issued by a country outside of Europe.